# Appending list to data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, append, rbind

I have created an empty data frame in R with two columns:

```
d<-data.frame(id=c(), numobs=c())
```

I would like to append this data frame (in a loop) with a list, `d1` that has output:

```
[1] 1  100
```

I tried using `rbind`:

```
d<-rbind(d, d2)
```

and `merge`:

```
d<-merge(d, d2)
```

And I even tried just making a list of lists and then converting it to a data frame, and then giving that data frame names:

```
d<-rbind(dlist1, dlist2)
dframe<-data.frame(d)
names(dframe)<-c("id","numobs")
```

But none of these seem to meet the standards of a routine checker (this is for a class), which gives the error:

```
Error: all(names(cc) %in% c("id", "nobs")) is not TRUE
```

Even though it works fine in my workspace.

This is frustrating since the error does not reveal where the error is occurring.

Can anyone help me to either merge 2 data frames or append a data frame with a list?

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch in the names of your data.frames. In the code, the second name is `numobs`, but in the error message, the second name appears to be `nobs`. Could you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: How is `d2` structured? Is it a list of length-two vectors?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are confusing the purpose of `rbind` and `merge`. `rbind` appends data.frames or named lists, or both *vertically*. While `merge` combines data.frames *horizontally*.

You seem to be also confused by `vector`'s and `list`'s. In R, `list` can take different datatypes for each element, while `vector` has to have all elements the same type. Both `list` and `vector` are one-dimensional. When you use `rbind` you want to append a *named* `list`, **not** a named/unnamed `vector`.

### Unnamed Vectors and Lists

The way you define a `vector` is with the `c()` function. The way you define an *unnamed* list is with the `list()` function, like so:

```
vec1 = c(1, 10)
# > vec1
# [1]  1 10

list1 = list(1, 10)
# > list1
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 10
```

Notice that both `vec1` and `list1` have two elements, but `list1` is storing the two numbers as two separate vectors (element `[[1]]` the vector `c(1)` and `[[2]]` the vector `c(10)`)

### Named Vectors and Lists

You can also create named vectors and lists. You do this by:

```
vec2 = c(id = 1, numobs = 10)
# > vec2
# id numobs 
# 1     10

list2 = list(id = 1, numobs = 10)
# > list2
# $id
# [1] 1
# 
# $numobs
# [1] 10
```

Same data structure for both, but the elements are named.

### Dataframes as Lists

Notice that `list2` has a `$` in front of each element name. This might give you some clue that `data.frame`'s are actually `list`'s with each column an element of the `list`, since `df$column` is often used to extract a column from a dataframe. This makes sense since both `list`'s and `data.frame`'s can take different datatypes, unlike `vectors`'s.

### The `rbind` function

When your first element is a dataframe, `rbind` requires that what you are appending has the same names as the columns of the dataframe. Now, a named `vector` would not work, because the elements of a `vector` are not treated as columns of a dataframe, whereas a named `list` matches elements with columns if the names are the same:

To demonstrate:

```
d<-data.frame(id=c(), numobs=c())

rbind(d, c(1, 10))
#   X1 X10
# 1  1  10

rbind(d, c(id = 1, numobs = 10))
#   X1 X10
# 1  1  10

rbind(d, list(1, 10))
#   X1 X10
# 1  1  10

rbind(d, list(id = 1, numobs = 10))
#   id numobs
# 1  1     10
```

Knowing the above, it is obvious that you can most certainly also `rbind` two dataframes with column names that match:

```
df2 = data.frame(id = 1, numobs = 10)

rbind(d, df2)
#   id numobs
# 1  1     10
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the routine checker appears to be looking for columns labeled "id" and "nobs".  If that doesn't match your file output, you'll get that error.

I'm taking what is probably the same class and had the same error; correcting my column names made that go away (I'd labeled the 2nd one "nob" not "nobs"!)  Now I've gotten the routine checker to complete correctly, or so it seems... but it outputs three data files, and the first and last files are correct but the second one yields "Sorry, that is incorrect."  No further feedback.  Maddening!

No point posting my code here as it runs fine locally with all the course examples, and it's kinda hard to debug when you don't know what the script is asking for.  Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

That d2 object is being printed as an atomic vector would be. Maybe if you showed us either dput(d2) or str(d2)  you would havea better understanding of R lists. Furthermore that first bit of code does not produce a two column dataframe, either.

```
> d<-data.frame(id=1, numobs=1)[0, ]             # 2-cl dataframe with 0 rows
> dput(d)
structure(list(id = numeric(0), numobs = numeric(0)), .Names = c("id", 
"numobs"), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")
> d2 <- list(id="fifty three", numobs=6)          # names that match names(d)
> rbind(d,d2)
           id numobs
2 fifty three      6
```